# Use of Protected Constructor

Tags: java

We usually create public constructor and for singletone reason create the private constructor, so I was wondering if what is the use of protected constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8207494

Answer (score 1):

A sub-class of an abstract class would need to call the constructor of its super class, so a protected constructor would make sense.

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected A (int something)
    {

    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public B (int something)
    {
        super(something);
    }
}
```

Actually, in case of an abstract super-class, you don't need the constructor to be protected, since you can't create an instance of A even if the constructor was public. But even if A is not abstract, you might want to define a constructor of A that can only be invoked by sub-classes of A.